# Distance between points - elementary geometry.

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

I read this paper:
http://people.cs.uchicago.edu/~niyogi/papersps/NiySmaWeiHom.pdf .

I have a problem with the proof of the Lemma 4.1. I don't know how to get the following formula $A=b\sin(\theta)+\sqrt{\epsilon^{2}-b^{2}\cos^{2}(\theta)}$.

I suppose that I should use some formulas with trigonometry and Pythagorean theorem, but I don't see it.

Please, help me with my problem.

Answer (score 1):

Use the orthogonal projection of $q$ onto $T_p^{\perp}$ to split $A$ into two line segments. The bottom one has length $b\sin \theta$, while for the top one you need to apply Pythagoras' Theorem.

Credits: Fig. 1 from the linked paper.

[image]

Comment: Thank You for Your answer. It was as easy as I supposed.

Comment: @bergarius You're welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Ok. Consider this.

$A=(A-q)+q$ where q is the vertical distance above the x-axis.

Create a line perpendicular to A that passes through q. This will divide the triangle into two other triangles

- Part 1: The bottom trialngle
  Consider the bottom triangle. It's a simple right triangle. From here we see that $q=b \sin(\theta)$.
- Part 2.
  The top triangle is also a simple right triangle. Note that from the bottom triangle, we also have that the distance of the line dividing the large triangle into two smaller triangles is $b \cos(\theta)$. If we want to get distance $A-q$, we need only apply the Pythagorean Theorem again. This gives $A-q=\sqrt{\epsilon^2-{b \cos(\theta)}^2}$.

To get distance A, then just add $A-q$ to $q$.

Comment: Beat to it. Now that I look, Arnaud definitely said it better.